# Wierd Undefine Variable Error

Tags: php, debugging

Below is my Code which I am running on WAMP 2.5. The works fine on MAMP but on WAMP it keeps giving `undefined` variable error. For instance `$dbhandle` is undefined error as per php while I have explicitly defined it way before line# 49. What I am feeling that PHP interpreter is not accessing file sequentially. It read directly thing between `html` and `/html` rather reading from top.

```
<?
    ini_set('display_errors',0);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include_once 'config.php';
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbhandle = null;
    $row = null;

    $username = $config['user'];
    $password = $config['password'];
    $hostname = $config['server'];
    $db = $config['db'];
    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die(mysql_error($dbhandle));

    $selected = mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle)or die(mysql_error($dbhandle));

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        $query = "Delete from posts WHERE sb_id = $id";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle) or die(mysql_errno($dbhandle));

        $query = "Delete from comments WHERE post_id = $id";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle) or die(mysql_errno($dbhandle));
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Latest Fb Posts
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
        #container{padding-top: 5%;padding-left: 5%;}
        .post{background-color: #e7ecfd;width:90%;padding: 1%;margin-bottom: 2%;}
        .post a{font-size: 80%;}
        .commentbox{font-size: 90%;font-family: Arial;padding:1%;;margin-top: 2%;margin-bottom: 2%;width: 75%;background-color: #dadbe1;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;}
        .author{display: block; width: 50%;color: #1e3493;font-weight: bold;font-size: 70%;padding-bottom: 2%;}
        .date{color: #d2d4df;display: block;width: 30%;margin-top: 2%;}
    </style>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by sb_id Asc";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle);
        ?>
        <div id="container">
            <?
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
                    {
            ?>
                        <div class="post">
                            <?= $row->content ?>
                            <span class="date">
                                <?
                                    $newDate = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($row->post_date));
                                ?>
                                <?= $newDate ?>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                          <?
                            $queryComment = "SELECT * from comments where post_id = $row->sb_id";
                            $resultComment = mysql_query($queryComment, $dbhandle);
                            while ($rowComment = mysql_fetch_object($resultComment))
                            {
                          ?>
                                <div class="commentbox">
                                    <span class="author">Adnan Commented:</span>
                                    <?= $rowComment->content ?>
                                </div>
                            <?
                            }
                            ?>
                            <a href="index.php?id=<?= $row->sb_id ?>">Delete</a>
                        </div>
            <?
                    }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is wearied except mysql_* usages. the code seems fine.please stop using mysql_* because it's officially deprecated and use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Removing that did not solve the issue